# NGINX: "client sent invalid method while reading client request line"

Tags: docker, nginx, alpine-linux

After setting up SSL for Nginx and making a request, I receive a garbled response with the cryptic message `client sent invalid method while reading client request line`.

I generated the certificate using Let's Encrypt in an Alpine Docker container (for context, not relevant to the error).

Here is a screenshot:

[image: client sent invalid method while reading client request line]

Simplified Nginx virtual host configuration follows:

```
server {

    listen 443;

    ssl_certificate /vsdroot/letsencrypt/live/yourdomain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /vsdroot/letsencrypt/live/yourdomain.com/privkey.pem;

    ssl_dhparam /vsdroot/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
    include /vsdroot/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;

    root /vsdroot;

    location / {
        index index.html;
    }
```

**Security Note:** My SSL key is located inside the Nginx docroot for local testing only, **do not do this** on production, or anywhere for that matter!

Answer (score 9):

I narrowed down the directive causing the issue and was able to consistently replicate the issue by modifying the `listen` line on the server block.

**Reproduction.** Produce gibberish along with `client sent invalid method while reading client request line` error.

*Bad `listen` line*:

```
server {
    listen 443;
```

Slightly different error, but still no dice:

```
server {
    listen ssl;
```

*Product*:

[image: Error screenshot]

...

**FIXED.** Error goes away and I'm able to serve my request (plain html, `fastcgi_pass`, etc).

*Configuration:*

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
```

...

Profit Screenshot  :

[image]

Took more than I'd like to admit to narrow the cryptic error down to the single `listen` directive .

Comment: I dn't know what the hell happened with me too.... on one server using just listen 443 was working but on another it was not... only when I did listen 443 ssl; it started working... btw thanks for the information :)

Comment: I also had this issue when a client was trying to communicate with ssl over a non-ssl port. Same solution, add `ssl` to the port's listen decleration